# Extending Python with C++: boost vs native

Tags: python, c++

I need to make an existing C++ class usable from python, so I've been exploring using Boost.Python vs the native functionality provided by python directly. I coded up the first non-trivial example from the Boost [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html):

```
struct World 
{
    World(std::string s) : msg(s) { }

    void set(std::string m) { msg = m; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }

    std::string msg;
};
```

whose equivalent via the native extension I coded as:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    std::string* msg;
} World;
```

with, for instance, `greet()` and `set()` implemented as:

```
static PyObject* World_greet(World* self)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s", self->msg->c_str());
}

static PyObject* World_set(World* self, PyObject* args)
{
    const char* msg = NULL;

    if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &msg)) {
        self->msg->assign(msg);
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement `World` with `PyObject`? Is there a better alternative... should `msg` be a `std::string`, a `PyObject*`, or a `PyStringObject*` instead of a `std::string*`? If it should be one of the others - why and what would `World_greet()` and `World_set()` look like with the different type?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see if it works?

Comment: @Marcin It works with a `std::string*`, but just because it works doesn't mean it's the correct solution. I cannot get it to work with `std::string` though, which doesn't mean it's impossible either.

Comment: even the official doc of python tell you that is better to use third party tools for this. I tested boost.python, swig and cython. boost.python is the great looser (complex, veeeeery long compilation time cause of the full template approach), and I finaly prefered cython cause it can do a lot more than create a python binding, but swig can make binding for a lot of language

Comment: @LudovicViaud I will check both out, thank you. SWIG looks pretty nice. I'm not concerned about compilation time at all, just total development time (the boost tutorial example does take a *long* time to build, but even still crushes the native implementation for how much more stuff you have to write...)

Comment: for learning/development time swig is really great, most of the time you just need headers and it will works. After that you can write python only code to define a nicer interface if needed. Sometimes you will want to define how ownership of resources is handled, and you will need to add some lines of swig

Comment: @LudovicViaud swig does seem awesome. Is there a way to get it to output just an .so instead of having both a .py and an .so?

Comment: the .so is for the low level API to the compiled code. It's not very useful alone, because all your classes will be made of simple functions. The .py define the high-level, useful interface. If you just want the low level interface just erase the .py. If you want the high-level interface with just one file, i think you can hack the .py and put the content of the .so in a bytearray and create tmpfile to import etc ... I don't recommend you to do that

Comment: Cool. Thanks! Anyway, SWIG-love aside, I would like to know how to it natively too, at least for curiosity's sake.